# R: obtain lower.tri elements of a correlation matrix & identify each element with their respective row&colnames

Tags: r, matrix

say I have a correlation matrix

```
> cor.Mat = round(cor(mtcars), 2)
> cor.Mat
       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
mpg   1.00 -0.85 -0.85 -0.78  0.68 -0.87  0.42  0.66  0.60  0.48 -0.55
cyl  -0.85  1.00  0.90  0.83 -0.70  0.78 -0.59 -0.81 -0.52 -0.49  0.53
disp -0.85  0.90  1.00  0.79 -0.71  0.89 -0.43 -0.71 -0.59 -0.56  0.39
hp   -0.78  0.83  0.79  1.00 -0.45  0.66 -0.71 -0.72 -0.24 -0.13  0.75
drat  0.68 -0.70 -0.71 -0.45  1.00 -0.71  0.09  0.44  0.71  0.70 -0.09
wt   -0.87  0.78  0.89  0.66 -0.71  1.00 -0.17 -0.55 -0.69 -0.58  0.43
qsec  0.42 -0.59 -0.43 -0.71  0.09 -0.17  1.00  0.74 -0.23 -0.21 -0.66
vs    0.66 -0.81 -0.71 -0.72  0.44 -0.55  0.74  1.00  0.17  0.21 -0.57
am    0.60 -0.52 -0.59 -0.24  0.71 -0.69 -0.23  0.17  1.00  0.79  0.06
gear  0.48 -0.49 -0.56 -0.13  0.70 -0.58 -0.21  0.21  0.79  1.00  0.27
carb -0.55  0.53  0.39  0.75 -0.09  0.43 -0.66 -0.57  0.06  0.27  1.00
```

I can obtain the lower.tri of this matrix:

```
> cor.Mat[lower.tri(cor.Mat)]
 [1] -0.85 -0.85 -0.78  0.68 -0.87  0.42  0.66  0.60  0.48 -0.55  0.90  0.83 -0.70  0.78 -0.59
[16] -0.81 -0.52 -0.49  0.53  0.79 -0.71  0.89 -0.43 -0.71 -0.59 -0.56  0.39 -0.45  0.66 -0.71
[31] -0.72 -0.24 -0.13  0.75 -0.71  0.09  0.44  0.71  0.70 -0.09 -0.17 -0.55 -0.69 -0.58  0.43
[46]  0.74 -0.23 -0.21 -0.66  0.17  0.21 -0.57  0.79  0.06  0.27
```

but I also wish to keep the corresponding row&colnames of the vector elements in the correlation matrix

Is it possible to obtain something like:

```
 mpg--cyl mpg--disp   mpg--hp mpg--drat   mpg--wt mpg--qsec   mpg--vs   mpg--am  ...
    -0.85     -0.85     -0.78      0.68     -0.87      0.42      0.66      0.60  ...
```

For all lower.tri elements?

Answer (score 0):

`as.data.frame(as.table(cor.Mat)` Is the key to this transformation:

```
cor.Mat <- round(cor(mtcars), 2)   # make data
cor.Mat[upper.tri(cor.Mat, diag = TRUE)]<-999   # fill the upper tri and diag with dummy value
cor.Mat<-as.data.frame(as.table(cor.Mat))   # turn into three columns ### This is the key step
cor.Mat<-cor.Mat[cor.Mat$Freq!=999,]   # drop the rows with dummy values 
cor.Mat$newname<-paste(cor.Mat$Var1, cor.Mat$Var2, sep = "--")   # make the new column name
cor.Mat<-cor.Mat[,c(4,3)]   # keep and rearrange the columns

head(cor.Mat)
#    newname  Freq
#2  cyl--mpg -0.85
#3 disp--mpg -0.85
#4   hp--mpg -0.78
#5 drat--mpg  0.68
#6   wt--mpg -0.87
#7 qsec--mpg  0.42
```